# Pager will come by default in blogs template or not?

Tags: 7, theming, paging, nodes

I am using blogs  module in one of the website. I have created a template file for that, I want to add pager if blog items exceeds that 10. So my question is in that template file how can I use pager. It will display by default or is there any other ways to add pager to that template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating a custom template for the blogs created by the blog module you will have a variable called $pager available to you in that template. Wherever you want it displayed you can just add something like this:

```
 <div id="blog-pager" class="pager"><?php echo $pager ?></div>
```

If you look in [blog.pages.inc](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/modules/blog/blog.pages.inc?h=7.x) you'll see that the "pager" is added to the "$build" render array in each of the menu callback functions defined in that file.